# Aligning on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to align some text on the same line, my CSS is this:

```
#logo {
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 250px;
}
```

And my code:

```
    <div id="logo">Text Here
      <div align="right">Text There</div>
    </div>
```

this is what it shows:

[image]

would you guys happen to know what it is that I'm doing wrong? I tried inline styling for the second div, for a `padding: 0; and margin: 0;` but didn't work.

I just want it to be on the same line, but adjusted on the right. Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place divs side-by-side in a container

```
<div style="width:600px;">
    <div id="logo">Text Here</div>
    <div style="float:right;">Text There</div>
</div>
```

Then add `display:inline-block;` CSS property to both the divs.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJRXk/)

Comment: Thank you! I've been out of it for awhile now with HTML & CSS. and `float: right` was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I will, it'll let me after 5 minutes. But it works perfectly now. I will accept once it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

divs are automatically set to be in 'block' format, which means they will not allow anything to align with them.
To fix your problem, but this code in the div tag with 'align="right"':

```
style="display: inline;"
```